# Binary search Java list with key extractor

Tags: java

Say I have:

```
class Item {
   int id;
   int type;
}
```

I can do this:

```
List<Item> items;
Item itemToFind;
Comparator<Item> itemComparator;
Collections.binarySearch(items, itemToFind, itemComparator);
```

However, say that instead of the whole object, I'm only given a property of the object, say `type` for the above example. Assuming the list is sorted by that property, is there a standard method in Java or some established library to do something to this effect:

```
List<Item> items;
Function<Item, Integer> typeExtractor = Item::getType;
int typeToFind;
Comparator<Integer> typeComparator = Integer::compare;
binarySearch(items, typeExtractor, typeToFind, typeComparator);
```

without additional overhead (e.g. converting `List<Item>` to `List<Integer>` to call `Collections.binarySearch` on or similar)?

Comment: I don't see why would you want to extract the types. You can write a comparator which compares only the types. The binary search will return the item from where you can get the type.

Comment: As Ervin said, when you have a list of Items, you should implement a comparator of items and use that for your binary search

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi The [signature](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T,java.util.Comparator)) is `binarySearch​(List<? extends T> list, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)`, so you need to provide `T key`. In my case, that would be `Item key`, but I only have `int typeToFind`.

Comment: @RoyShahaf See above note.

Comment: @levantpied look at the answer by juan

Comment: @RoyShahaf I saw it already - can you clarify how would I call `Collections.binarySearch` if I *don't* have an `Item itemToFind`, but only `int typeToFind`?

Comment: You should wrap your `typeToFind` into an `Item` assuming that it is possible. Otherwise you should create a new array.

Comment: Solutions presented so far are just hacks requiring class tricks, while what we really need is a `binarySearch` method that adds a key extractor as a parameter: `binarySearch(List<? extends T> list, U key, Comparator<? super U> c, Function<? extends T, U> keyExtractor)`.

Answer (score 1):

The comparator still would be `Comparator<Item>`. What you would change is the implementation of the comparator to evaluate upon the type instead of the id.

```
Comparator<Item> comparator = new Comparator<Item>(){
    public int compare(Item a, Item b) 
    { 
        return a.getType() - b.getType(); 
    } 
}
```

*Item, would need to have the getter for type or the attribute made public. The same if using the id.*

> However, not sure how you suggest I would call
>   Collections.binarySearch

The usage doesn't change (what changes is how the comparison is done inside the comparator object):

```
Item itemToFind = new Item();
itemToFind.setType(typeToFind);
Collections.binarySearch(items, itemToFind, comparator );
```

**After some thought on the subject:**

An alternative to use an `Item` as a needle is to base the `Comparator` on an Interface that `Item` and the needle implement.

An interface to return int values:

```
 public interface Intgettable{
     public int getInt();
 }
```

`Item` should have to implement this interface:

```
public class Item implements Intgettable{
     private int id;
     private int type;

     public void setId(int id){ 
         this.id = id;
     }
     public void setType(int type){ 
         this.type = type;
     }
     public int getId(){
         return id;
     }
     public int getType(){
         return type;
     }
     public int getInt(){
         return type;
     }
 }
```

The key to search will be an `Intgettable` which can be created:

1 - Using a class that extends `Intgettable`.

```
public static class MyItemKey implements Intgettable{
     private int value;

     public MyItemKey(int v){
         this.value = v;
     }

     @Override
     public int getInt(){
         return value;
     }
}

MyItemKey typeToFind = new MyItemKey(6);
```

2 - As an anonymous class inside the method.

```
Intgettable typeTofind = new Intgettable(){
        private int value = 6;
        public int getInt(){
            return value;
        }
};
```

3 -  Or using the lambda version:

```
Intgettable typeTofind = ()->{return 6;};
```

The `Comparator` will be:

```
Comparator<Intgettable> comparator = new Comparator<Intgettable>(){
        public int compare(Intgettable a, Intgettable b){
            return a.getInt() - b.getInt();
        }
};
```

And finally use it in the binary search:

```
Collections.binarySearch(items, typeToFind, comparator );
```

Comment: Yeah, Item has a `getType` getter as usual. How would I call `Collections.binarySearch` with the above comparator if I don't have `Item`, but only it's type (i.e. `int typeToFind` as in the question)?

Comment: Sure, but it actually does, this line: `Function<Item, Integer> typeExtractor = Item::getType;`. However, not sure how you suggest I would call `Collections.binarySearch`, can you add that to your answer?

Comment: The line I put in my previous comment implies `Item` has a `getType` method. I hoped that it's assume getters and setters are a standard thing in Java and elided. Please assume they are there. Your updated answer is not an answer - didn't I mention a few times that I *do not* have `Item itemToFind`, but only `int typeToFind`?

Comment: An Item still would be necessary, so you create an Item to be used as the needle and set the type on it.

Comment: I added an alternative to use an Item as the needle.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that in a `Collection<T>` the binary search implementation of java allows to search only for items of type `T`. In order to search for another type which is a part of `T`, you can do the following:

1. Wrap the other type inside `T`, in your case this should look like this:

```
List<Item> items;
int typeToFind;

Item itemToFind = new Item(/* random value for id */ 0, typeToFind);
int index = binarySearch(items, itemToFind , (a, b) -> a.getType() - b.getType());
```

Some important notes to add here:

  - the comparison of items should depend only and only on `type`, otherwise you may end up with some nasty bugs;

  - the list of items should be sorted. The sorting should depend only and only on `type`(basically using the same comparator as before)

2. Create a new list from the initial list:

```
List<Items> items;
int typeToFind

int index = binarySearch(items.stream.map(item -> item.getType()).collect(Collectors.toList()), itemToFind);
```

As far as I know, the standard library for Java does not provide binary search implementation with a comparator for key equality. If these options does not satisfy you, probably you should search for a library or implement your own search.